# Background field method for QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, path-integral

I want to evaluate the 1-loop beta function for massless QED using background field method. This is my trying. First we separate the gauge field into
$$A_\mu(x)=\bar{A}_\mu(x)+\delta A_\mu(x)$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{\psi}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\bar{D}_\mu)\psi
+\bar{\psi}(\gamma^\mu \delta A_\mu)\psi
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\bar{D}\psi=\partial_\mu \psi+i\bar{A}_\mu \psi
\end{align}
So the quadratic term in fermion fields in the path integral is
\begin{align}
\int [ d\bar{\psi}d\psi]
\exp\big[i\int d^4x \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\bar{D}_\mu)\psi\big]
=\det(\bar{{\not} D})
\end{align}
ignoring higher order terms in the integration such as $\bar{\psi}\delta A \psi$. In order to do the expansion and obtain a similar operator as in gauge contribution, we work with the square of Dirac operator
\begin{align}
\Delta_{\rm spinor}&\equiv
\bar{{\not} D}^2
=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\bar{D}_\mu\bar{D}_\nu
=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\{\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu\}
+[\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu]\Big]\bar{D}_\mu\bar{D}_\nu \nonumber\\[5pt]
&=\bar{D}^2 -2i\Big(\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu]\Big)
\bar{D}_\mu\bar{D}_\nu
=\bar{D}^2+\bar{F}_{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}\nonumber\\[5pt]
&=\partial^2+\Delta_1+\bar{F}_{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\Delta_1=i\bar{A}_\mu\partial^\mu+i\partial_\mu \bar{A}^\mu
\end{align}
should be thought of as acting on some $U(1)$ charged matter
\begin{align}
\Delta_1\lambda=i\bar{A}_\mu\partial^\mu\lambda+i\partial_\mu \big(\bar{A}^\mu \lambda\big)
\end{align}
The contribution of spinor field to the path integral is
\begin{align}
\log\det&\Delta_{\rm spinor}=\mathrm{tr} \log\Delta_{\rm spinor}=\mathrm{tr}\log\big(\partial^2+\Delta_1+\bar{F}_{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}\big)\nonumber\\[5pt]
=&\mathrm{tr} \log\big(\partial^2\big)+\mathrm{tr} \log\Big[1+\big(\partial^2\big)^{-1}
\big(\Delta_1+\bar{F}_{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}\big)\Big]
\nonumber\\[5pt]
=&\mathrm{tr} \log\big(\partial^2\big)
+\mathrm{tr}\big(\partial^2\big)^{-1}
\big(\Delta_1+\bar{F}_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}\big)
\nonumber\\[5pt]
&-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\big(\partial^2\big)^{-1}
(\Delta_1)(\partial^2\big)^{-1}
(\Delta_1)\Big]
-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\big(\partial^2\big)^{-1}
\bar{F}_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}
\big(\partial^2\big)^{-1}
\bar{F}_{\rho\sigma} S^{\rho\sigma}\Big]
\end{align}
In the last equality, the first term is a uninteresting constant. I do not know how to calculate the second term, namely $\mathrm{tr}\big(\partial^2\big)^{-1}
\big(\Delta_1+\bar{F}_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}\big)$ . Is there any reference for this? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You want to get zero. Obviously the term proportional to $\bar F_{\mu \nu}$ is zero for $\bar F$ is antisymmetric. Rewrite the rest in momentum space.

Comment: @nwolijin   yes, I want  zero. Can you write down more  details? Thank you.